# How to extract text between 2 matching pattern to multiple files?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression, cut

I have binary file and I want to split it into separate files by START and END patterns.
Example of input:

```
yut786y= 3&*%^#$%fsd{'StartOfFile': sdflklfasdgjw723gsdf67asfr55a64
asduf hfna089FUAO
AHF78QAB6A SDFADSFGfh asiug6a8osiofh7qw8e6fgha
fq9w46tygvkabsdjfnhc :End}}fji8yEBFBOA NFmc
```

Similar blocks(but not the same) can repeat in input file

Result should be:

```
{'StartOfFile': sdflklfasdgjw723gsdf67asfr55a64
asduf hfna089FUAO
AHF78QAB6A SDFADSFGfh asiug6a8osiofh7qw8e6fgha
fq9w46tygvkabsdjfnhc :End}}
```

Block per file

I tried `awk '/{'\''StartOfFile'\'':/,/End}}/' file > export;`
and then `awk '/StartOfFile/{filename=NR".txt"}; {print >filename}' export` to split into files.

But first and last lines still have undesired chars. How to cut them? Chars and number of them not known

Comment: extend you input with few "Similar blocks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with below single awk:

```
awk -v RS="{'StartOfFile'" 'NR>1{sub(/End}}.*/,"End}}"); print RS$0>NR-1".txt"}' infile
```

I ran on below sample input:

```
{'StartOfFile': Unix.stackexchange.com End}}
yut786y= 3&*%^#$%fsd{'StartOfFile': sdflklfasdgjw723gsdf67asfr55a64
asduf hfna089FUAO
AHF78QAB6A SDFADSFGfh asiug6a8osiofh7qw8e6fgha
fq9w46tygvkabsdjfnhc :End}}fji8yEBFBOA NFmc

72 YOY398Y 9Y9&y&*t*#&y(*yH{'StartOfFile':uih4yUH OG8YG*^t&^t*&o y(yt&*wt*&(0
jfhi hwuw hfuweh012r892u 098Y&*T*#^98 yHO
OFUH idueg&*#trt& goe
ouh#ye(e#y( geiyfgefyg #O WIBCJHvKKJSLSDOLSL*6
asds:End}}JKDSHFLAJHFLAJSDHFLIAUHFILU7869786
```

The output was/is as following split into 3 files:

> **1.txt**
>
> ```
> {'StartOfFile': Unix.stackexchange.com End}}
> ```
>
> **2.txt**
>
> ```
> {'StartOfFile': sdflklfasdgjw723gsdf67asfr55a64
> asduf hfna089FUAO
> AHF78QAB6A SDFADSFGfh asiug6a8osiofh7qw8e6fgha
> fq9w46tygvkabsdjfnhc :End}}
> ```
>
> **3.txt**
>
> ```
> {'StartOfFile':uih4yUH OG8YG*^t&^t*&o y(yt&*wt*&(0
> jfhi hwuw hfuweh012r892u 098Y&*T*#^98 yHO
> OFUH idueg&*#trt& goe
> ouh#ye(e#y( geiyfgefyg #O WIBCJHvKKJSLSDOLSL*6
> asds:End}}
> ```